# Create rule to restrict special characters in table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a rule to restrict special characters to be entered into a column.
I have tried the following. But it didnt work.

```
CREATE RULE rule_spchar
AS
@make LIKE '%[^[^*|\":<>[]{}`\( );@&$]+$]%'
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Didnt work means what?

Comment: Don't use `RULE`. [Deprecated for years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839967/rules-are-deprecated-whats-instead-tsql).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your can create a `Check Constraint` on this column and only allow `Numbers`and `Alphabets` to be inserted in this column, see below:

### Check Constraint to only Allow Numbers & Alphabets

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_No_Special_Characters 
       CHECK (Column_Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
```

### Check Constraint to only Allow Numbers

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Only_Numbers 
       CHECK (Column_Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

### Check Constraint to only Allow Alphabets

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Only_Alphabets 
       CHECK (Column_Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%')
```

Comment: Interesting, but can you make one that bars `^*|\\":<>[]{}\`\( );@&$]+$` ?

Comment: Except that (Column_Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%')  limits not to only alphabet, but to only latin/western-style alphabet(s) (but then, it will allow the turkish i or German Umlauts for example, which isn't an ASCII character)... If you only want ascii characters, change the column collation, and exclude numbers with a check constraint. Oh, this wouldn't be the place to mention that the Chinese have 3 ways to represent numbers (western, traditional signs, formal signs), and the Indians (the real ones) use other number signs as well. If you want only integers, set the type to integer...

Comment: Is there a reason you use `NOT LIKE`, combined with a negation in the RegExp (the `^` symbol), instead of just doing `LIKE '[A-Z0-9]'` or perhaps `LIKE '^[A-Z0-9]$'` ?

Comment: @sanderd17 `x LIKE '[A-Z]'` matches only a *single character* (implicitly `len(x) = 1` must be true) and it becomes prohibitive to do `x LIKE '[A-Z]' OR x LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z]' OR ..`. There is no way to use a regular-expression like (hah!) `*` modifier with `LIKE`. LIKE has very restricted pattern productions and *there is no regular expression involved*, even if `^` is also used in other (regular expression) contexts. The double-negative finds "any not-approved character" and then considers the input valid only "if there was none (ie. no not-approved characters)".

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember Microsoft's plans for the features you're using or intending to use. [`CREATE RULE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064(v=sql.105).aspx) is a deprecated feature that won't be around for long. Consider using `CHECK CONSTRAINT` instead.

Also, since the character exclusion class doesn't actually operate like a RegEx, trying to exclude brackets `[]` is impossible this way without multiple calls to `LIKE`. So collating to an accent-insensitive collation and using an alphanumeric inclusive filter will be more successful. More work required for non-latin alphabets.

M.Ali's `NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'` Should serve well.

Answer (score 1):

M.Ali's answer represents the best practice for the solution you describe.  That being said, I read your question differently(i.e What is wrong with they way you're implementing the like comparison.)

1. You are not properly escaping wildcard characters.
2. The expression `'AB' LIKE '%[AB]%` is true.  The expression `'ZB' LIKE '%[^AB]%'` is also true, since that statement is the equivalent of `'Z' LIKE '[^AB]' OR 'A' LIKE '[^AB]'`  Instead, you should use `'YZ' NOT LIKE '%[^AB]%'` which is the equivalent of `'Y' NOT LIKE '%[^AB]%' AND 'Z' NOT LIKE '%[^AB]%'`
3. You didn't escape the single quote or invisible characters.  Take a look at the the [ASCII characters.](http://www.asciitable.com/)  You would be better served implementing a solution like M.Ali's and adding any characters you do *not* wish to exclude.

The following script demonstrates the formation of a complex wildcard statement that consists of special characters.

```
-- Create sample data
-- Experiment testing various characters
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id INT NOT NULL, string1 varchar(10) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @temp
        (id,string1)
SELECT 1, '12]34'
UNION 
SELECT 2, '12[34'
UNION 
SELECT 3, '12_34'
UNION 
SELECT 4, '12%34'
UNION 
SELECT 5, '12]34'

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @SQL_Wildcard_Characters VARCHAR(512),
@Count_SQL_Wildcard_Characters INT,
@Other_Special_Characters VARCHAR(255),
@Character_Position INT,
@Escape_Character CHAR(1),
@Complete_Wildcard_Expression VARCHAR(1024)
SET @Character_Position = 1

-- Note these need to be escaped: 
SET @SQL_Wildcard_Characters = '[]^%_'
-- Choose an escape character.  
SET @Escape_Character = '~'
-- I added the single quote (') ASCII 39 and the space ( ) ASCII 32.  
-- You could also add the actual characters, but this approach may make it easier to read.
SET @Other_Special_Characters = '*|\":<>{}`\();@&$' + CHAR(39) + CHAR(32)

-- Quick loop to escape the @SQL_Wildcard_Characters
SET @Count_SQL_Wildcard_Characters = LEN(@SQL_Wildcard_Characters)
WHILE @Character_Position < 2*@Count_SQL_Wildcard_Characters
BEGIN
    SET @SQL_Wildcard_Characters = STUFF(@SQL_Wildcard_Characters,@Character_Position,0,@Escape_Character)
    SET @Character_Position = @Character_Position + 2
END
-- Concatenate the respective strings
SET @Complete_Wildcard_Expression = @SQL_Wildcard_Characters+@Other_Special_Characters

-- Shows how the statment works for match
SELECT ID, string1, @Complete_Wildcard_Expression AS [expression]
FROM @temp
WHERE string1 LIKE '%['+@Complete_Wildcard_Expression+']%' ESCAPE @Escape_Character

-- Show how the statement works fo non-match
SELECT ID, string1, @Complete_Wildcard_Expression AS [expression]
FROM @temp
WHERE string1 NOT LIKE '%[^'+@Complete_Wildcard_Expression+']%' ESCAPE @Escape_Character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_checkspecial_characters(@String varchar(MAX))
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result INT;
SELECT @Result=(CASE WHEN @String COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%[(<~!@/#$%^&>)]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
RETURN @Result;
END
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 