# User defined Rules on user defined data type doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

I want to define a new user defined data type with a check rule to limit its value, say,

```
CREATE RULE dbo.test
AS
@a LIKE '[A-Z][0-9]'
```

Then I create the user type with this rule:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[uType] FROM [varchar](2) NULL

EXEC sys.sp_bindrule @rulename=N'[dbo].[test]', @objname=N'[dbo].[uType]'
```

Then test it:

```
declare @a uType
set @a = 'K1'
set @a = 'AB'
select @a
```

The final value for `@a` works out without popping out any errors as if the rule didn't exist. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little bit of research I found that rules aren't getting checked when creating variable. They are checked when you are trying to insert values into a table with column of defined type. Try below script and see that it will generate error:

```
create table tbl(col uType);
insert into tbl values ('ba'), ('A1')
select * from tbl
```

But this approach is deprecated and it's recommended not to use it: [Rules are deprecated, what's instead (TSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839967/rules-are-deprecated-whats-instead-tsql)

Comment: this works good. One thing to point that it seems the table must be defined without binding the type to rule first, i.e., sequence must be like `CREATE TYPE ... CREATE TABLE tbl(col userType) ... EXEC sp_bindrule ...`